# integrate Firebase with Wix

Tags: javascript, firebase, velo

i have problems integrating Firebase in Wix- Website.

I added a node_module called "firebase" and added the following code to my backend:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/auth'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
...
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export function SignIn (Email, Password) {
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
}
```

then i added this to frontend:

```
import {SignIn} from 'backend/Functions';

$w.onReady(function () {

});

export function LogInButton_click(event) {
    SignIn($w("#EmailLabel").value, $w("#PasswordLabel").value).then($w("#text30").text = "Log-in Succed!")
    console.log("pressed");
}
```

When I press the button I receive the error:

"firebase.auth is not a function"

Thank you for help!

Tim

Comment: That means `firebase` and or `firebase.auth()` is not loaded.

Comment: @Luka This means that I added the node incorrectly?

Comment: I have no idea. Try `console.log(firebase.auth())` or `console.log(firebase)` within the `SignIn function` for sure.

Comment: @Luka console.log(firebase) works but console.log(firebase.auth()) returns the error "firebase.auth is not a function" How can I fix this?

Comment: Expand results from `console.log (firebase)`, is there an `auth function`?

Comment: @Luka No there is no firebase.auth(). The result is: `__esModule: true
apps: Array(1)
0: {...}
firebase_: "[Circular ~.payload.0.args.0]"
isDeleted_: false
name_: "[DEFAULT]"
automaticDataCollectionEnabled_: false
options_: {...}
container: {...}
SDK_VERSION: "7.15.5"
INTERNAL: {...}
components: {...}
node: {...}
localStorage: {...}
sessionStorage: {...}
default: "[Circular ~.payload.0.args.0]"`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

with

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

or just

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

without

```
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

but [not recommended](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) for production apps.

Comment: If so, I have no idea. try clearing the cache, history or other related matters.